# Timeout issue in Sails.js testing

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sails.js

This is my lifecycle.test.js file:

```
var sails = require('sails');

// Before running any tests...
before(function(done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift, even if you have a bunch of assets.
  this.timeout(5000);

  sails.lift({
    // Your Sails app's configuration files will be loaded automatically,
    // but you can also specify any other special overrides here for testing purposes.

    // For example, we might want to skip the Grunt hook,
    // and disable all logs except errors and warnings:
    hooks: { grunt: false },
    log: { level: 'warn' },

  }, function(err) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }

    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    // (for example, you might want to create some records in the database)

    return done();
  });
});

// After all tests have finished...
after(function(done) {

  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  // (e.g. you might want to destroy the records you created above)

  sails.lower(done);

});
```

This is the FooController.test.js file:

```
var supertest = require('supertest');
var sails = require('sails');

describe('FooController.foo', function() {

  describe('#foo()', function() {
    it('should respond 200', function (done) {
      supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get('/foo')
      .expect(200)
    });
  });

});
```

And this is the command that runs when npm run test is run:

```
"test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout=10000 test/lifecycle.test.js test/integration/**/*.test.js",
```

But I am getting this error: Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done() is very important

```
  describe('#foo()', function() {
    it('should respond 200', function (done) {
      supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get('/foo')
      .expect(200, done)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer and remove the `done()` call and just pass the function name as the second argument to the `expect(200, done)` method? Because the way you passed it any test would pass.

Comment: Yep, sorry, didnt test that scenario. Fixed the answer.